# How to create multiply tabs for class in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to create tabs for each class in tkinter. But faced with a problem that they are laying on each other.

I already tried to create a new class for Notebook, but the result is the same. Now I stopped at this variant.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding='10 10 15 15')
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N+S+W+E)
        self.connectionCheck()
        self.connectionConf()
        self.measureFrame()
        self.meas()
        self.logview()
        self.running = None
#It have other functions. But I think they not really necessary

class Mapframe(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.mapframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding='10 10 15 15')
        self.mapframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N + W + E + S)
        self.choosefiles()
        self.meas()

window = Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = Application(notebook)
tab2 = Mapframe(notebook)
notebook.add(tab1, text='Tab1')
notebook.add(tab2, text='Tab2')
notebook.grid(row=0, column=0)
notebook.mainloop()
notebook.quit()
```

So, as I say they lay on each other. And the tabs not even showing when the program is launch.

Upd: after change `master` to `self`.[image: master to self]

Comment: Change `ttk.Frame(master, ...` to `ttk.Frame(self, ...`

Comment: I tried it, doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a class that inherits from a `Frame`, with the intention of holding other widgets, a cardinal rule is that all child widgets should be children of that class.

In your case, you're not doing that. You're creating a notebook, adding frames to the notebook, but the widgets inside each frame are being set as children of the root window. They need to be children of the frames (eg: `self`).

You need to define `self.mainframe` and `self.mapframe` like in the following example.  Note the use of `self` rather than `master` as the first parameter:

```
self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding='10 10 15 15')
...
self.mapframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding='10 10 15 15')
```

The only place you should be using `master` as the parent of a widget is when calling `ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)`. At no other time should you be putting widgets inside of `master`

Comment: I tried to change `master` to `self`. Now I see the tabs, but the are near two frames still laying on each other.

Comment: @D53E: Add a image to your question, to show the result.

Comment: @stovfl I added the image

Comment: @D53E: The same fault: You didn't follow the **"cardinal rule"** described in the answer.